# PHP mkdir not working after rmdir

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir, rmdir

I have a chunk of code that tests if a directory exists, deletes it if it exists, and creates a new directory over it. It should be fairly simple.

```
if(is_dir($directory)){
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
              new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
              RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
            );
    foreach($files as $fileinfo){
        $todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
        $todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
    }
    rmdir($directory);
    //var_dump(is_dir($directory));
}

clearstatcache();
mkdir($directory,0744);
```

If the directory does not exist yet, the `mkdir()` works just fine. But if the directory does exist, the `rmdir()` loop does its job, but PHP throws an error:

```
PHP Error[2]: mkdir(): Permission Denied
```

The commented `var_dump()` line shows me that PHP still thinks `$directory` is a directory even after the `rmdir()` call. So I use `clearstatcache()` to update it, but it still won't detect that the directory has been deleted. And when I look it up in the file system, the directory has in fact been deleted.

If I run the script again (while the directory is gone), it works just fine.

Can anyone figure out how to resolve this error? If it makes a difference, I am running this as a PHP command line script on my Win7/XAMPP dev environment.

edit:

Thanks to Wee Kiat and Phillip for the answer. The solution was to use `unset($files)` before `rmdir()` to close the recursive iterator, which was still keeping `$directory` open and causing `mkdir()` to choke. See their code below.

Comment: "Permission Denied" is a clear error

Comment: What happens if you pass true to `clearstatcache();`? Can you put the `var_dump( is_dir());` directly before the `mkdir()`?

Comment: @ Dagon - Permission denied is not clear in this case because it only gives the error 50% of the time. @nickb - The `var_dump()` gives the same output in both locations, whether before or after `clearstatcache()`. It seems like `clearstatcache()` is not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it appears that $files is the variable that is causing the problem, what you need to do is to unset $files after the foreach loop and you will be able to mkdir().

```
if(is_dir($directory)){
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
              new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
              RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
            );
        foreach($files as $fileinfo){
            $todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
            $todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
        }

    unset($files);

    rmdir($directory);
    //var_dump(is_dir($directory));
}
mkdir($directory,0744);
```

But i do not know why $files is causing the problem. any ideas?

Comment: Well, I guess the RecursiveIteratorIterator does still have an open handle on the directory until PHP shutdown where RecursiveIteratorIterator is destroyed and the directory is removed afterwards. This would cause mkdir() to fail but still seem as if the directory was removed (because it is, right after the script finishes). Therefore destroying the RecursiveIteratorIterator at the right time solves the problem. (I would suggest to use `unset($files);`, though).

Comment: Thanks Philipp for the great explanation, i've edited the solution based on your suggestion using unset($files)

Comment: You guys are amazing! Thanks so much. I wasted about 4 hours of my life on this yesterday...